# Converting a ListView to GridView

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview

I am trying to wrap a template and pass the DataItem to the wrapper which is currently in LayoutTemplate however it breaks when i try to add the DataItem inside that and no idea why (im not a asp guy) however after readying up i see that this should be possible with GridView but have no idea how i would rewrite this to do that. Could someone maybe help me on a solution for this?

C#

```
protected void rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem listItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)listItem.DataItem;
    }
}
```

If you see where title="" and description="" i want to ideally pass some data to those like: (but this break and does not work) ive come so far to get it this far but last bit and would be awesome if someone could help out as i need to release this this morning. If we can keep using the ListView would be great!

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalogueTitle")%>
```

ASPX

```
<asp:ListView ID="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <Catalogue title="" description="">
            <div runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder"></div>
        </Catalogue> 
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <Course>
            <CourseTitle><a onclick="linkcourse("<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseID")%>");return false;" href="#" title="Launch <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle")%>"><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((String)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle").ToString().Length > 25 ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle").ToString().Remove(22) + "..." : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle")))%></a></CourseTitle>
            <RatingsEnabled><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ratingsEnabled")%></RatingsEnabled>
            <Rating><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rating")%></Rating>
            <RatingCommentsEnabled><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ratingCommentsEnabled")%></RatingCommentsEnabled>
            <Comment><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%></Comment>
            </Course>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you want to show some tool tip for the anchor tags, if so please try this once.

ASPX is

```
<asp:ListView ID="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <Catalogue title="" description="">
        <div runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder"></div>
    </Catalogue> 
</LayoutTemplate>
<GroupTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <Course>
        <<CourseTitle><a id="aCourse" runat="server" href="#" </a></CourseTitle>
        <RatingsEnabled><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ratingsEnabled")%></RatingsEnabled>
        <Rating><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rating")%></Rating>
        <RatingCommentsEnabled><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ratingCommentsEnabled")%></RatingCommentsEnabled>
        <Comment><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%></Comment>
        </Course>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and code behind is

```
protected void rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem listItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)listItem.DataItem;
        HtmlGenericControl aCourse = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("aCourse");
        if (dataItem["CourseTitle"].ToString().Length > 25)
        {
            aCourse.InnerHtml = "Launch " + dataItem["CourseTitle"].ToString().Substring(0, 22) + "...";
            aCourse.Attributes.Add("title", "Launch " + dataItem["CourseTitle"].ToString() + "...");
        }
        else
            aCourse.InnerHtml = "Launch " + dataItem["CourseTitle"].ToString();
        aCourse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "linkcourse(" + dataItem["CourseID"].ToString() + ");return false;");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just needed to pass some data to <Catalogue title="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalougeTitle")%>" description=""> in the GroupTemplate as if i do that in ItemTemplate it just repeats itself and i need to wrap only once around them all.